# Кастмизация цветов яндекс карт на основе json файла

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть вопрос. Яндекс не так давно запустил сервис кастомизации яндекс карт под названием редактор стилей карт, который выдаёт json файл со стилями карты подключаемыми через api, по какой-то причине ни при каких условиях этот файл не инициализируется для работы в браузере, его просто игнорирует. Может есть у кого пример кода полный на котором получилось завести свои стили для элементов или может кто поделиться опытом реализации на этом инструменте?

Answer (score 0):

Пример добавления слоя с тёмной подложкой карты и удалением меток POI:

```
map.addChild(new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer({
        theme: 'dark',
        customization: [{
                "elements": "label.icon",
                "stylers": {
                    "visibility": "off"
                }
            }
        ]
}));
```

Если нужно работать с файлом, подгружайте его напрямую в [customization](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/ref/#customization).